# Probability of investments (Expected value?)

Tags: probability

help with a probability question would be greatly appreciated. Read this in a business magazine this morning and wondering how they arrived at the probabilities.

Problem:
 Suppose that each of your company's 20 product lines has an opportunity to invest \$10 million with a 50% chance of receiving \$30 million and a 50% chance of losing the full \$10 million.

Conclusion:
Theres a 6% chance the company as a whole would lose any money at all. Additionally, there is a 41% chance of earning more than \$100 million (after deducting the \$200 million investment) and a 75% chance of earning at least \$40million.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Formatting note:  in Latex, the dollar sign has meaning.  if you want to use it in text (generally discouraged for this reason) you need to put a back slash in front of it.  If you click on edit you can see the syntax I used.  Note the similar syntax around the percent symbol.

Comment: When you say "receive $30$ million" dos that mean $20$ million profit or $30$ million profit?

Comment: @lulu thank you!

Comment: @saulspatz I’m assuming $30 million in profit

Comment: @Mibi I think they mean $20$ million.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that "receive $\$30$ million" means you earn a profit of $\$20$ million.  Then there are $2^{20}$ possible outcomes, and assuming that the success or failure of all the investments are independent, each has the same probability: $2^{20}.$  If $7$ investments make a profit, then the company earns $(7\cdot20-13\cdot10)$ million.  If $6$ or fewer show a profit, then the company loses money.  The probability that the company loses money is 
$$2^{-20}\sum_{k=0}^6\binom{20}{k}\approx0.057659$$

I haven't worked out the others, but I assume they're much the same.